# CKEditor uploadimage change name=upload

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, lotus

I use plugin uploadimage CKEditor.

How to properly configure the plugin to transfer its name to the field, rather than the standard application.

Upload URL:

```
config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '/uploadfiles.nsf/uploadfiles?CreateDocument';
```

plugin use:

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

It should be like this:

```
<input type="file" name="%%File.4325814d00377965.3570884048d1a3c44325812a003cb5ad.$Body.0.96">
```

Tell me which parameter is responsible for this

Comment: At the moment, I took another plug-in ( http://ckeditor.com/addon/simpleImageUpload ) and adapted it to the lotus

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the default file upload behavior before sending the request as follows -

```
// Get CKEditor instance
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;


// Modify CKEditor's default request data object on 'fileUploadRequest' event
editor1.on('fileUploadRequest', function(evt) {

    // Copy contents of 'upload' image field to a new field with 'new_name'
    var requestDataObject = evt.data.requestData;
    requestDataObject['new_name']=requestDataObject['upload'];

    // Delete old 'upload' image field from the request data object
    delete requestDataObject['upload'];
} );
```

Here's the official documentation where they talk about editing the default request object with new headers and data items - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_file_upload.html#editor-side-configuration.

Unfortunately, they leave it to you to figure out a way to modify the existing 'upload' field by simply saying -

> Note that the default file to be uploaded is also a property of
>   evt.requestData named upload and it can be overwritten when
>   neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your file's name in the response of your server.

see a example in php :

```
if (file_exists("img/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]))
{
 echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] ;
}
```

you can also see the documentation of CKEditor on upload file : http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload

Comment: I also thought about this, but it's impossible to do so on the Lotus Domino.